# what does super(Myclass.class) in constructor mean in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, comparator, super

I am seeing the following kind of  code repeatedly in `Mapreduce` programs. This is just a snippet of code taken out. The entire code is available [here](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch08/src/main/java/MaxTemperatureUsingSecondarySort.java)

what does the `super` call in the constructor do? Does it call the constructor of `IntPair.class`? why is such a call necessary.

```
public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
        protected KeyComparator() {
          super(IntPair.class, true);
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
          IntPair ip1 = (IntPair) w1;
          IntPair ip2 = (IntPair) w2;
          int cmp = IntPair.compare(ip1.getFirst(), ip2.getFirst());
          if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
          }
          return -IntPair.compare(ip1.getSecond(), ip2.getSecond()); //reverse
        }
      }
```

Comment: Spend some time in reading [Oracle tutorial - Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it call the constructor of IntPair.class?

No, It's just a argument that is passed in the super class constructor.

> why is such a call necessary?

To avoid the call of no arguments constructor of the super class that is by default added by the compiler.

If there are multiple constructors in the super class then you can be specified which constructor of the super class should be called based on arguments.

---

Sample code: (Look at the output when `KeyComparator` object is created)

```
class WritableComparator {
    public WritableComparator(){
        System.out.println("default constructor is called");
    }
    public WritableComparator(Class<?> clazz, boolean flag) {
        System.out.println("two arguemnts constructor is called");
    }
}

class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public KeyComparator() {
        //super(); // by default added by the compiler
        super(IntPair.class, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: so just to avoid the `super()`, the `super(Intpair.class, true)` is made correct?. so does it serve any other purpose or not?

Comment: yes you are going in right direction. There are multiple constructor of a class based on inputs you can decide to call the desired one.

Comment: so in this case, if I would have made `super(String.class,true)` would that be fine. But I guess, that will conflict with the `compare` method I am implementing..

Comment: That's correct as per my code. Now if you are facing any issue then share the code or ask separate question.

Answer (score 4):

super(), when used in the constructor will call the constructor of the class which is extended. In this case, it will call the WriteableComparator constructor. You can see more details on super in the java documentation here:
[Java super link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

In particular, see the section titled "Subclass Constructors".

Answer (score 1):

`IntPair.class` notation is used to get object **describing** this class. Like here:

`Class<?> type = Integer.class;`

This `type` variable is not an instance of `Integer` class, but instance of object describing `Integer` type.

Some classes requires you to pass them `type` of objects you want them to work with. Then, they can for example create new instances of those classes, using this `type` object.

[more about Class class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)